# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ReactNativeBlobUtil.DocumentDir')

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-blob-util because rn-fetch-blob has not been updated since 5 years ago and I have this error which happens with rn-fetch-blob too:

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ReactNativeBlobUtil.DocumentDir')`

I am using react-native 0.68.1 and this only happened on android and not iOS.

If someone has already faced the issue.

"react-native": "0.68.1",
"react-native-blob-util": "^0.16.0",